# Is Oracle "pl/sql" collections assigned by value or by reference?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have one collection and need to copy this one to another.

For example:

```sql
TYPE my_table_type IS TABLE OF some_object;

procedure test(p_table IN my_table_type) is
  internal_table my_table_type;
begin
  internal_table := p_table;

  internal_table.extend;
  .... 
end;
```

This is an assignment by reference or by value?

Is that correct way copy nested tables?

I have tried. It seems to work fine.
But I couldn't find any reference in Oracle documentation.

Comment: IN - Actual parameter is passed by reference, see [Tab. 8-2](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/subprograms.htm#LNPLS659)

Answer (score 5):

The assignment in your example `internal_table := p_table;` is assignment **by value**.

Here's a little test to show how it works:

```
set serveroutput on
declare 
   TYPE my_table_type IS TABLE OF integer;
   table_ my_table_type := new my_table_type();
   internal_table my_table_type;
begin
  table_.extend(1);
  table_(1) := 123;
  dbms_output.put_line(table_(1)); --output is 123
  internal_table := table_;
  dbms_output.put_line(internal_table(1)); --output is 123


  table_(1) := 321;
  dbms_output.put_line(table_(1)); --output is 321
  dbms_output.put_line(internal_table(1)); --output is 123
end;
```

As you can see, the value in `internal_table` did not change which means we have two different collections.

Now, if you're talking about the input parameter of `test` procedure, it can be passed either by reference, or by value, which depends on argument's **mode**:

> **IN** parameters are always passed by reference.
>  
>   **IN OUT** or **OUT** parameters, by default, are passed by value. But, if you specify the **NOCOPY** option, they will be passed by reference.

You can read more about it here [Subprogram Parameter Modes](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/subprograms.htm#LNPLS657)

Comment: `IN` parameters are passed by reference, not by value.

Comment: @WilliamRobertson, sure. Updated the answer. Thanks